# jython input validation while loops map

Tags: loops, input, while-loop, jython, exit

I am trying to use a while true loop so that if i use a negative integer whilst the user trys input it exits out of the menu, my problem lies with my 2nd iteration of asking the user for input.

my first iteration:

```
choice=1
while choice1>=0:  
    choice1=requestInteger("Please enter the first city you would like to visit")
    while(choice1>9):
      choice1=requestInteger("Error, Please enter a city that corresponds with the number on the map")
```

my 2nd iteration straight under:

```
while choice2>=0:
  choice2=requestInteger("Please enter the first city you would like to visit")
  while(choice1>9):
    choice1=requestInteger("Error, Please enter a city that corresponds with the number on the map")
```

and third:

```
      choice3=1
  while (choice3>0):

    choice3=requestInteger("Please enter another city you would like to visit")
    while(choice3>9):
      choice3=requestInteger("Error, Please enter a city that corresponds with the number on the map")
```

The 2nd iteration never loops back it continues back onto the first loop. How can I fix this?